# Is there a recommended symbol for the empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

The symbols $\varnothing$ (`\varnothing`) and $\emptyset$ (`\emptyset`) are both used for the empty set.

Is there an official standard that recommends which one we should use?

Comment: Regarding which one is standard: These days what TeX does is standard. Which one do you get from \emptyset?

Comment: I use `\emptyset`, which formats as $\emptyset$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The second one. The first one is form \varnothing.

Comment: Thanks. Was actually a rhetorical question - my point was just that \emptyset is going to be standard.

Comment: However, $\varnothing$ looks much better and corresponds closer to the original symbol chosen by Bourbaki. Some of the choices in $\TeX/\LaTeX$ are bad choices (`\Re` and `\Im`, anyone?).

Comment: Presumably, one could go by the names, except that LaTeX uses `\equiv` for the normal congruence symbol and `\cong` is a tilde-equals usually used for more general equivalences, something I still find annoying.

Comment: It's odd that there is a `\varnothing` but not a `\nothing`. I always took the `var` in `\varepsilon` to mean "variant." Does it really mean "variable?" If so, is regular `\epsilon` not a variable?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think (strongly) that it's short for variant [peeve: the glyphs $\varepsilon,\vartheta,\varrho,\varkappa,\varphi$ are what were the standard glyphs for these letters when and where I learned the Greek alphabet, $\epsilon,\theta,\rho,\kappa,\phi$ were the variants].

Comment: @DanielFischer: I'm happy with $\theta$, $\rho$ and $\kappa$, but I much prefer $\varepsilon$ and $\varphi$. And I wonder who uses $\varpi$ for anything. Hmm, is there a $\varsigma$? (There was).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah, I forgot about $\varphi$. I strongly prefer $\varepsilon$ and $\varphi$, I find $\vartheta$ nicer than $\theta$ but not much. I prefer $\kappa$ to $\varkappa$, and I'm not really happy with either of $\rho$ or $\varrho$, I'd prefer something in between. The $\varsigma$ is a true variant because that letter had different glyphs depending on whether it occurred at the end of a word or in the middle/at the beginning ($\varsigma$ is the final variant). I don't know if that's still so in modern Greek. In Hebrew there are several letters with final variants.

Comment: I've never seen that variant $\theta$, personally. A lot of typesetting and format choices come from physical typesetting days. I'm sure it is much easier to create a typeset $\theta$ than a typeset $\vartheta$, for example, especially if you want it small but readable in an exponent. @DanielFischer

Comment: The final sigma is still  `ς` in modern Greek.

Comment: @DanielFischer The fact that a symbol is used in Bourbaki doesn't automatically mean it is good. I find $\varnothing$ bad, for instance, because it denotes “diameter” in technical contexts.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The name `\varnothing` was chosen by the AMS (at least, by the developers of `amssymb`).

Comment: @Daniel: I learned $\epsilon$, $\theta$, $\kappa$, $rho$, and $\phi$ as standard when I studied Classical Greek long ago; for mathematics I prefer all of these except $\phi$, for which I prefer $\varphi$. As for the original question, I consider $\varnothing$ preferable to $\emptyset$, but that’s clearly a matter of taste, and I consider what $\LaTeX$ does to be largely irrelevant.

Comment: @Brian I guess it really depends on time and place. My old German-Greek dictionary uses $\vartheta,\varrho$, the approximately eighty years newer Greek-German dictionary uses $\theta,\rho$, both agree on $\varepsilon,\varkappa,\varphi$ however. I completely agree that it is a matter of taste, of course, for the empty set as for the glyphs of the Greek letters.

Comment: @Daniel: I expect so, yes. You aroused my curiosity enough to go take a look at [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Griechisches_Alphabet#Klassische_Zeichen); it takes as standard $\varepsilon,\theta,\kappa,\rho$, and $\varphi$, though I’ve no idea to what extent it represents current German practice. And it does mention all of the usual variants.

Comment: My pet peeve is the notation for the empty set in Papoulis and Pillai's "Probability, Random Variables and Stochastic Processes" (2002): on p.15, they say "The *empty* or *null* set is by definition the set that contains no elements. This set will be denoted by $\{\emptyset\}$". I cringe every time. Anybody seen that anywhere else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both typographical variants of the symbol are in wide use. There is no difference in meaning, and readers can be expected to recognize either as a symbol for the empty set. Many people have quite distinct (and different) opinions about which one looks "best" or "right", though.

It's up to personal preference, really.

(The fact that TeX names one of them `\emptyset` and the other `\varnothing`, suggesting it is a "variant" symbol, merely reflects the preference of TeX's author Donald Knuth for the $\emptyset$ form, not a collective decision by any group of mathematicians).

Comment: As I already commented several times, I find $\varnothing$ a good symbol for plumbers. `;-)` Out of the joke: in technical papers it usually denotes a diameter.

Comment: @egreg there is a \diameter symbol in the wasysym package.

Comment: @wythagoras Yes, see [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xzmdf.png)